# Database for web based customer queue

Tags: database-design

I'm looking for the best database to use for a web based customer queue service.  I would like to avoid using Oracle and want a free DB.  The database needs to mimic a customer service queue kiosk in a lobby but be scalable for multiple sites.  Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

Choose from postgres, mariadb or firebird

- mariadb - the free variant of mysql
- postgres - clever
- firebird - clever and with a oracle-compatible option (fyracle)

regards,
/t